# Deleting a ROW from MySQL database using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a `delete.php` file with yes/no buttons that call `deleteRecord.php` to delete the selected row from the database.

The problem seems to be that I'm not passing the variable for the `ProjectID` through to the **deleteRecord** file.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

---

delete.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);
require('includes/conn.inc.php');
require('includes/functions.inc.php');
$sProjectID = safeInt($_GET['ProjectID']);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, ProjectImage, LanguageUsed, ApplicationUsed, Description FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $sProjectID);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($ProjectID, $ProjectName, $ProjectImage, $LanguageUsed, $ApplicationUsed, $Description);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<input name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo
$ProjectID; ?>">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Delete <?php echo $ProjectName; ?></title>
<link href="styles/cms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
<h1>Delete <?php echo $ProjectName; ?></h1>
<?php
require('includes/nav.inc.php');
?><p>Hello </p><?php echo "$sProjectID" ?>
</header>

<form name="form1" method="get" action="process/deleteRecord.php">
<p>Are you sure you wish to delete <?php echo $ProjectName; ?>?</p>
   <p>
    <input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Delete">
  </p>
    </form>

<form name="form2" method="" action="listall.php" id="saveForm">
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
</form>

<?php
require('includes/footer.inc.php');
?>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

deleteRecord.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);
require('../includes/conn.inc.php');
require('../includes/functions.inc.php');
// sanitize user variables
$sProjectID = safeInt($_POST['ProjectID']);
// prepare SQL
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $sProjectID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
//header("Location: ../index.php");
// redirect browser
exit;
// make sure no other code executed
?>
```

Comment: nit-picking: There is no Mysqli database. [mysqli](http://docs.php.net/mysqli) is just one of the php-apis to interact with a MySQL server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write the hidden field inside your form and change your method to `POST`.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="process/deleteRecord.php">
    <p>Are you sure you wish to delete <?php echo $ProjectName; ?>?</p>
    <p>
        <input name="ProjectID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo
$ProjectID;
?>">
        <input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Delete">
    </p>
</form>
```

As per @VolkerK comment below, put the input element "within" the form element instead of the one before the `<html>` tag.

Comment: Just for clarification: Put the `input` element "within" the form element _instead_ of the one _before_ the `<html>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for this. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the GET method for doing the same:

Change in delete.php:

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="process/deleteRecord.php?ProjectID=<?= $ProjectID ?>">
    <p>Are you sure you wish to delete <?php echo $ProjectName; ?>?</p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="del" id="del" value="Delete">
    </p>
</form>
```

Change in deleteRecord.php:

```
$sProjectID = safeInt($_GET['ProjectID']);
```